# .NET Forms ReportViewer Authentication

Tags: .net, winforms, reportviewer

What is the correct way to supply WindowsCredentials to the ReportViewer control in order to authenticate to a Report Server?

When browsing to the reports a popup will ask for credentials, but i'm not able to provide the credentials in code? Have tried numerous sollutions on the web, but nothing seems to fit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it eventually!

```
reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials.NetworkCredentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
```

Comment: This doesn't work for web forms - IReportServerCredentials only specifies a getter for the NetworkCreditials property.

-dave

Comment: I'm pretty sure my problem was related to the webControl? it was some time ago will check it for you.

Comment: Credentials aren't actually passed in the soap request.

Both machines aren't domain joined.